# Is there any possible way to remove key which start with specific key words and end with specific key word in javascript / node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, string, replace

I am trying to replace specific letter which is present in my string but the problem there is multiple letter I want to replace so I have to write all the replace code manually

eg:-

```
let string= "<!-- ct:hold -->Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. \n<!-- /ct:hold -->Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \n\t<!-- ct:ol -->It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged<!-- /ct:ol -->. <!-- ct:query {\"queryId\":8,\"query\":{\"perPage\":\"10\",\"pages\":0,\"offset\":0,\"postType\"} -->It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<!-- /ct:query>"

string.replace(/<!-- ct:text -->/g, "")
.replace(/<!-- ct:hold -->/g, "")
.replace(/<!-- ct:ol -->/g, "")
.replace(/<!-- ct:asset -->/g, "")
.replace(/<!-- ct:ques -->/g, "")
.replace(/<!-- ct:data -->/g, "")
```

```js
let string= "<!-- ct:hold --><!--start-->Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. \n<!-- /ct:hold -->Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \n\t<!-- ct:ol -->It has survived not <!--end-->only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged<!-- /ct:ol -->. <!-- ct:query {\"queryId\":8,\"query\":{\"perPage\":\"10\",\"pages\":0,\"offset\":0,\"postType\"} -->It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with <!--start-->desktop publishing software like<!--Fragrement--> Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<!-- /ct:query -->";

string =string.replace(/<!--?\s+\/?ct:.*?-->/g,"");

console.log(string)
```

as here You can see this are some small value which I am replacing but there are
large keywords which I want to remove

for eg:-

```
string.replace(/<!-- ct:text -->/g, "")
.replace(/<!-- ct:hold -->/g, "")
.replace(/<!-- ct:ol -->/g, "")
.replace(/<!-- ct:asset -->/g, "")
.replace(/<!-- ct:ques -->/g, "")
.replace(/<!-- ct:data -->/g, "")
.replace(/<!-- ct:query {\"queryId\":8,\"query\":{\"perPage\":\"10\",\"pages\":0,\"offset\":0,\"postType\"} -->/)
.replace(/<!-- ct:spacer {\"height\":120} -->/)
```

Is there any possible I can remove only the values which start with `<!-- ct:` and if end with `-->` and doesn't matter how long the replace text is

Comment: Did you tried regex?

Comment: no @ShivamSood as I don't know what is the best regrex to remove all the text which is start with `<!-- ct:` and `-->`

Comment: [`/<!--\s+ct:.*?-->/g`](https://regex101.com/r/olNflD/1) respectively [`/<!--?\s+\/?ct:.*?-->/g`](https://regex101.com/r/olNflD/2) for the OP's updated/specified question.

Comment: Thank you @PeterSeliger :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the solutions/variants already linked with the above comment, there is a 3rd variation which is less strict in matching syntactically in/valid comments like the last one from the OP's example data.

The below code shows the different results from using ...

- variant 2 ... [`/<!--?\s+\/?ct:.*?-->/g`](https://regex101.com/r/olNflD/2)
- variant 3 ... [`/<!--?\s+\/?ct:.*?>/g`](https://regex101.com/r/olNflD/3)

```js
const sampleText = `
<!-- ct:hold -->Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
<!-- /ct:hold -->Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. 
    <!-- ct:ol -->It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged<!-- /ct:ol -->. <!-- ct:query {"queryId":8,"query":{"perPage":"10","pages":0,"offset":0,"postType"} -->It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of
  Lorem Ipsum.<!-- /ct:query>`;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/olNflD/2]
const regXComment2 = /<!--?\s+\/?ct:.*?-->/g;

// see ... [https://regex101.com/r/olNflD/3]
const regXComment3 = /<!--?\s+\/?ct:.*?>/g;

console.log(
  sampleText.replace(regXComment2, '')
);
console.log(
  sampleText.replace(regXComment3, '')
);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { min-height: 100%!important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: hi @peter can you help me if I want to replace `<!--` and `-->` as I made some changes in your code `.replace(/<!--\s+.*?-->/g, "")` but its not removing `<!--start--> <!--end-->` and other which are starting with `<--` and end with `-->`

Comment: @Vikas ... Of cause it does not. [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/) has an _Explanation_ section where one can read what each part of the pattern does. Your new regex e.g. features `\s+` which means it matches at least one whitespace character which results in not covering  e.g. `<!--start-->` and `<!--end-->` since both do not feature the required whitespace after the opening sequence of `<!--`. Solution  ... remove `\s+` from your new regex.

Comment: oh got it thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string.replace(/^<\!-- ct:.*-->$/gi, "");
```

Update:

As per @MonkeyZeus' s suggestion, without lazy evaluation you might have a very bad result if you have multiple of those sub-strings to match in your string, this is safer:

```
string.replace(/<\!-- ct:.*? -->/gi, "");
```

This will match all the single substrings in your string: https://regex101.com/r/DxwRD6/1

Comment: It's not worth me writing a separate answer but you should really suggest a lazy quantifier `ct:.*?`

Comment: What would the lazy quantifier do, is it a performance thing?

Comment: @Gus It's a "disaster avoidance" thing. https://regex101.com/r/HAw6q1/1

Comment: hi @Cesare its working fine those are start with `<!-- ct:` and ends with `-->` but its not removing the `\n\t<!-- ct:` `-->` or `\n<!-- ct:` `-->` is there any way we can remove if it attached to string ?

Comment: See my edited answer, I think the `^` and `$` need removing in order to match any position in the string

Comment: Hi @Gus I have added code snippet of your code its not removing

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you don't want to use regex or replace, you could use [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser), then just return the text content which won't include the comments

```js
let string = "<!-- ct:hold -->Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. \n<!-- /ct:hold -->Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. \n\t<!-- ct:ol -->It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged<!-- /ct:ol -->. <!-- ct:query {\"queryId\":8,\"query\":{\"perPage\":\"10\",\"pages\":0,\"offset\":0,\"postType\"} -->It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.<!-- /ct:query>"

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(string, 'text/html')

console.log(doc.all[0].textContent)
```

Comment: DomParser dont work in nodejs ? So I have to use `xmldom` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regex wildcard match (`.`) and repeat 1 or more times modifier (`+`) to match any characters within the comment after the ct: part.  Also per @MonkeyZeus's comment, a lazy quantifier (`?`) is needed so that it doesn't match from the start of the first comment all the way to the end of the last one in the string: `/<\!-- ct:.+? -->/g`.

Comment: My answer has an actual explanation.  I forgot I had edit privileges :)

Comment: Hi Gus i Tried your condition its not working can you check I have updated my question for reference

Comment: I think it's because you're doing `string.replace()` - you need `string = string.replace()` as replace returns a new string

Comment: Hi @Gus its working now but I am trying to replace the other part which is `<!-- /ct:` and ends with `-->` by doing this `.replace(/<\!-- /ct:.+? -->/g, "")` but its giving me syntax error is there any possible i can remove other part to like this ?